# Wicket excel Page expired

Tags: java, excel, wicket

After using  WebResponse to export excel then clicking a Link gives Page expired error.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code and explain a bit more.

Comment: please edit that code into your question; formatting functionality is built in. It's hard to read in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session expired page usually appears when your pages are not bookmarkable and you make a request for a page to the server but the server has a different version of the page that you have requested. It shouldn't have anything to do with the session time out which is defined in the web.xml file.

As a good practice, your pages should have a constructor with PageParameters. Also be careful with the popup pages because they usually generate these kind of errors when they are not using PageParameters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your classes that don't extend wicket components use `implements Serializable`, otherwise you will often see a Page Expired error.

If this doesn't help, copy and paste the error logs so we can see the exception being thrown.

Comment: Hi,

How can i open a link  with a different pagemap so that i expect not to get page Expired error.

<code>
Link link = new Link{

  public void onClick() {
     // how can i set a new page map here ?
  }

}
</code>

Comment: Page map? Isn't that a single instance? What are you trying to achieve?